# Example of a dominating map

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Unfortunately the book that i am reading (Algebraic curves by Fulton) has no examples, so i am trying to find an example of a dominating map that would be helpful for the understanding of the definition.

We call a rational map $\phi:X \rightarrow Y$ is dominating if the image $f(U)$ is dense in $Y$, where $f:U \rightarrow Y$ is any morphism representing the map $\phi$, $U$ is an open subvariety of $X$.

Can we say that the projection $\mathbb{A^{2}} \rightarrow \mathbb{A}$ is a dominating map?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: OK, let's see: what is the image of this map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other examples are the following: let $H$ be the hyperbola $xy=1$ defined in $\mathbb{A}^2_{\mathbb{R}}$, then the projections
\begin{gather}
p_1:(x,y)\in H\to x\in\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{R}}\\
p_2:(x,y)\in H\to y\in\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{R}}
\end{gather}
are dominant.

A silly example is the inclusion of an open subvariety in an irreducible variety.

**Update.** An intersting example is the Cremona transformation
\begin{equation}
f:[x_0:x_1:x_2]\in\mathbb{P}^2_{\mathbb{R}}\to[x_1x_2:x_0x_2:x_0x_1]\in\mathbb{P}^2_{\mathbb{R}}.
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

Surjective maps are definitely dominating right?

Edit: Yes, it is dominating.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/625024)

Comment: I have answered the question. Maybe for you content, I will add a phrase that says "Yes".